# Adding predefined ribbon buttons to custom addin

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

We have a third party ribbon installed on MS Office 2013 Word, Excel and Outlook. We also have our own department custom ribbon.

What I need to do is hide the third party ribbon but include a couple of buttons on our custom ribbon to invoke specific buttons on the third party ribbon.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you still having an issue with the control references?

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle the ribbon's visibility based on a variable using the callback `getVisible`.

```
<tab idMso="TabYourThirdPartyRibbon" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
```

If you can, reference the `idMso` value for the 3rd party ribbon button.

If you can't, use Keytips/SendKeys.

*FYI, if the 3rd party ribbon didn't name the keytips for each control they can change if another ribbon is added/removed.

If you want to call a ribbon button from another ribbon, press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to get the keytip reference. As per below, I want to reference the `Script Help` ribbon which is `Y2`.

[image: ribbon tag screenshot]

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to show the control keytip control references for that ribbon. As per below, I want to reference the `Clean Data` button which is `Y7`.

[image: ribbon button tags screenshot]

Then you can use SendKeys to press those keytip references by adding the following procedure.

```
    public void CallButtonFromAnotherRibbon()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("%");
            SendKeys.Send("Y");
            SendKeys.Send("2");
            SendKeys.Send("%");
            SendKeys.Send("Y");
            SendKeys.Send("7");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Unexpected Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[Microsoft Documentation for KeyTips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.keytip.aspx)

[Microsoft Documentation for SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Interesting answer. If you have access to the IDs of the other Add-In, could you not also use idMso to place the control on your own ribbon tab without SendKeys? Do you know whether any of this varies based on whether one or the other is an application- or document-level Add-In?

Comment: If the keytips weren't assigned, they can change if another ribbon is added/removed. Yes, preferred method would be referencing the idmso if it's available. If the developer references more than one control in the  OnAction method then I don't think it would work.